# using class method to pull database info

Tags: php, mysql

**Overview:** I have a function that is supposed to pull a row of the db based on its id number

**Problem:** It seems my function is returning, but it isn't returning anything.

**Details:**

-I have 2 different files used here: db_class.php and character_pull.php

-Also I have a database that contains 1 table (characters) that does contain column "id"

-there are echo lines for debugging. I will give what the output is.

**character_pull.php:**

```
<?php

    include "db_class.php";

    echo "made it out here1";

    $classobject = new db_class();
    echo "made it out here2";

    $results = $classobject->getPlayerStats("1");

    print_r($results);

    echo "made it out here3";

        $id = "id: " . $results['id'];
        $name = "name: " . $results['charname'];
        $strength = "strength: " . $results['strength'];
        $defense = "defense: " . $results['defense'];
        $health = "health: " . $results['health'];
        $level = "level: " . $results['level'];
        $type = "type: " . $results['type'];
        $experience = "experience: " . $results['experience'];

    echo"<br/>"; 

    echo "made it out here4";
?>
```

**db_class.php:**

```
<?php

include "database_connect.php";

class db_class{



    public function getPlayerStats($id){

        echo "<br/>" . "making it in class1";

        $query = "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE id = $id";
        $result = mysqli_query($query);

        return $char = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


            $result ->close();
    }

}
```

?>

the output I receive when I run the page is this:

> made it out here1made it out here2 making it in class1made it out
>   here3 made it out here4

I have tried several things to fix this, but am having trouble figuring out what is wrong.

I know that this is probably extremely sloppy and primitive, but try not to laugh too hard and maybe you can help me out :P. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure there is a row in characters table with id "1"?

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get any errors with `include "database_connect.php";` being in the class declaration.

Comment: yes there is a row in the table with an id of 1

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` to the beginning of the script and show what errors/notices you receive after that.

Comment: `$result->close()` will never get called in your `getPlayerStats()` method because it is after a return statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of issues here.

It seems your DB class is quite incomplete.  To me, if I am creating a class to represent a DB connection and various operations I am going to make that connection in that class, not via some include (where I assume the connection is happening). The here is that the include will only occur conditionally if your code hits that line. In this case, since you have that include outside any actual function in the class (like a constructor) it will never be called.

I would suggest something like this to resolve this:

```
class db_class {
    protected $mysqli;
    private $db_host = 'your_db_host';
    private $db_user = 'your_db_user';
    private $db_password = 'your_db_password';
    protected $db_name = 'default_db_name';

    public __construct($db_host = NULL, $db_user = NULL, $db_password = NULL, $db_name = NULL) {
        if (!empty($db_host)) {
            $this->db_host= $db_host;
        }
        // validate other parameters similarly

        $mysqli = new mysqli($this->db_host, $this->db_use, $this->db_password, $this->db_name);

        if($mysqli->connect_error) {
            throw new Exception('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ', ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
        } else {
            $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
        }
    }

    // other class methods
}
```

You now have an object representing a mysqli connection store in `$this->mysqli`.

Your `getPlayerStats()` method might now look like

```
public function getPlayerStats($id) {
    if(empty($id)) {
        throw new Exception ('An empty value was passed for id');
    }
    // verify this is integer-like value
    $id = (string)$id;
    $pattern = '/^\d+$/';
    if (!preg_match($pattern, $id) !== 1) {
        throw new Exception ('A non-integer value was passed for id');
    }
    $id = (int)$id;

    $query = "SELECT id, name, strength, defense, level, health, type, experience FROM characters WHERE id = :id";
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    if (false === $result) {
        throw new Exception('Query error: ' . $stmt->error);
    } else {
        $obj = new stdClass();
        $stmt->bind_result($obj->id, $obj->name, $obj->strength, $obj->defense, $obj->level, $obj, health, $obj->type, $obj->experience);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
        return $obj;
    }
}
```

Note I used prepared statements here, which, you should get used to using as it is really best practice for querying databases. Note also I have added in handling of error cases all throughout the code.  You should get in the habit of doing this, as it will making debugging much easier.

Comment: Can you explain the instantiating of stdClass() and its return?

Comment: Yes, when using a prepared statement in this manner you need to bind the columns in the result set to variables. The `fetch()` then loads the values for those columns into the variables.  So I am just populating an empty stdClass object with the row data and returning it.

Comment: I wouldn't ever think about it. Thanks :) I would try to return some array variable

Comment: @MikeBrant I posted a new answer on this question because I'm stuck with a server error I keep receiving and having trouble debugging since I'm new to debugging php

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but I would move this above the class name:

```
<?php
include "database_connect.php";
    class db_class{
```

Comment: same results unfortunately :/

Comment: do a "show tables" in sql or something to make sure your connecting to the right database. Or just do a select * from table.  see what you get.